Second monitor does not reconnect after the screen locks
I have a laptop running Debian 12 with Gnome on Wayland. I'm using nvidia-driver with the default power settings: Power Mode = Balanced, Dim Screen = On, Screen Blank = 5 minutes.
Behavior: After 5 minutes of inactivity, both displays dim, then turn pitch black. Moments later, the external monitor briefly lights up with "Standby Mode" then turns dark again. The internal display while still black starts to glow.
Issue: When I press a key or move the mouse, the internal display "wakes up" to the login screen, but the second monitor stays off. If I reconnect the HDMI cable, or turn the monitor off/on, it just shows "Standby Mode" and turns black again. I can even move the cursor into it from the laptop's screen.
The same issue happens if I lock the screen manually. In this broken state, if I log out, then bring the login screen, both displays "wake up" as expected.
How can I make the monitor reconnect without logging out?

Debian: 12.6
Kernel: 6.1.0-23-amd64
GNOME: 43.9
Session: Wayland
Nvidia driver: 535.183.01

